# Robot framework and it's library how to put in POM to install on docker

Tags: maven, docker, pip, robotframework

Hi experts my use case is that I have to install robotframework and it's libraries on docker using POM.xml in maven style. because there are some limitations in my organization where we can not run chef on docker.
Here is I have created sample pom.xml. I need to do "pip install robotframework", pip install robotframework-databaselibrary" many more.
Can someone please help me out

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>robotframework</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <mkdir dir="${project.build.directory}/Library" />
                                <untar src="${project.build.directory}/Library/${robotframework.version}.tar.gz" compression="gzip" dest="${project.build.directory}/robotframework" />
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
<plugin>
 <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
 <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
 <executions>
   <execution>
     <id>0.0.2</id>
     <phase>generate-sources</phase>
     <goals>
       <goal>exec</goal>
     </goals>
     <configuration>
       <executable>pip install robotframework</executable>
     </configuration>
   </execution>
 </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: in my laptop I do pip install robotframework ==3.1.2 it works fine but I need to install all things in docker image while keeping all libraries in pom.xml

Comment: please share Dockerfile

Comment: Using Maven to install Python packages is unusual IME; it's usually limited to Java projects.  Why are you using this specific path?

Comment: Thanks for reply. Yes, I completely agree with you David. we have in-built framework  to execute test cases on prod and that is built in java so if I need to get success running robot test cases all libraries should be there. for an example I took help from here [link] http://www.mojohaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Do not have docker file as i have jenkins url where I do configure of project repo.

Comment: I have seen that it can been be done using requirement.txt and setup.py as mentioned in [Link]https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format. can any one guide me how to use in pom.xml